# response.sendRedirect not working with angular js and java servlet?

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

I have a following web application :

My html page : -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html ng-app="app">
    <title>BPL Auction 2016</title>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <!-- css -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angularref.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <div id ="header">
    <h3 id="title">BPL Auction 2016</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- Top content -->
            <div class="top-content">

                <div class="inner-bg">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
                                <div class="form-top">
                                    <div class="form-top-left">
                                        <h3>Login to our site</h3>
                                        <p>Enter your username and password to log on:</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-top-right">
                                        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-bottom">
                                    <form name="loginForm" role="form" method="post" class="login-form">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username or Company Email Id</label>
                                            <input type="text" ng-model="username" name="form-username" placeholder="Username or Email Id..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username" required>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" ng-model="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password" required>
                                            <span>{{validationMessage}}</span>
                                        </div>
    <div class="social-login-buttons">

                                        <button type="submit" ng-click="getDataFromServer()" class="btn">Sign in!</button>
    </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

My angular conrtoller js page

angularref.js

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller("MyController",function ($scope,$http){
    $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
        $http({
            method:'post',
            url:'login',
            data : {
                'username' : $scope.username,
                'password' : $scope.password
            }
        }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){

            $scope.validationMessage = data;

        }).error(function(data, status) {
              alert('Error with status code: ' + status); 
              alert(headers);
          });
    };
});
```

My Servlet class : -

```
package com.bpl.loginservlet;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginBPLServler
 */
public class LoginBPLServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SALT = "my-salt-text";

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
        String str = null;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(str);
        }
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());


        String username = jObj.getString("username");
        String unHashedPassword = jObj.getString("password");
        //signup(username, unHashedPassword);
        //response.sendRedirect("/BPL2016/second.html");

        // login should succeed.
        if (login(username, unHashedPassword))
        {
            System.out.println("user login successfull.");


            /*String successMessage ="Login Success. Redirecting ...";
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getWriter().write(successMessage);*/
            response.sendRedirect("http:/localhost:8080/BPL2016/second.html");
        }

        else
        {



        String error ="Invalid UserName or Password";
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write(error);


        }

    }


    public void signup(String username, String password) {
    String saltedPassword = SALT + password;
    String hashedPassword = generateHash(saltedPassword);
    insertIntoDB(username,hashedPassword);
}

public void insertIntoDB(String username,String hashedPassword)
{
     Connection con;
        PreparedStatement pst;


            try{

                //MAKE SURE YOU KEEP THE mysql_connector.jar file in java/lib folder
                //ALSO SET THE CLASSPATH
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bpl","root","root");
                            pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into tb_bpl_user_login(username,password) values(?,?)");
                            pst.setString(1, username);
                            pst.setString(2, hashedPassword);
                            pst.executeUpdate();


               }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }


}
public Boolean login(String username, String password) {
    Boolean isAuthenticated = false;

    // remember to use the same SALT value use used while storing password
    // for the first time.
    String saltedPassword = SALT + password;
    String hashedPassword = generateHash(saltedPassword);
    System.out.println(hashedPassword);
    String storedPasswordHash = getFromDB(username);
    if(hashedPassword.equals(storedPasswordHash)){
        isAuthenticated = true;
    }else{
        isAuthenticated = false;
    }
    return isAuthenticated;
}

public String getFromDB(String username)
{
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    String storedPassword = "";
    ResultSet rs;
    try
    {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bpl","root","root");
                 pst=con.prepareStatement("select password from tb_bpl_user_login where username =?");
                 pst.setString(1, username);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    storedPassword = rs.getString("password");
                    break;
                }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return storedPassword;
}
public static String generateHash(String input) {
    StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] hashedBytes = sha.digest(input.getBytes());
        char[] digits = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
        for (int idx = 0; idx < hashedBytes.length; ++idx) {
            byte b = hashedBytes[idx];
            hash.append(digits[(b & 0xf0) >> 4]);
            hash.append(digits[b & 0x0f]);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // handle error here.
    }

    return hash.toString();
}


}
```

I am not able to redirect to second.html page after entering the right credentials for logging. I am getting the response as : -

[image]

What changes should I make?

Comment: You're redirecting the ajax request, not the page itself. Unless AngularJS's ajax engine interprets redirects on ajax requests as full page redirects (which it does apparently not, given this question), you're going need to write the desired target URL to the response body and fiddle around with `window.location` yourself. This problem is at least not caused by Java Servlets, but by a misunderstanding of how ajax works.